# The use of Indirect object pronoun Le

Tags: pronombres

I came across this phrase in a Spanish textbook.

*"Le gustaria darle algo especial"*

I know about the direct and indirect object pronouns in Spanish, but I can't figure this one out. Why are there two "Le"s in this sentence? Is it a mistake or a specific use? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Remember that Spanish uses the third person for polite address: “[A Usted]ᵢ leᵢ gustaría darleₓ algo especial [a él(la)]ₓ” (where the subscript ‘ᵢ’ and ‘ₓ’ show what pronoun refers to what noun).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without more context it is hard to be sure but the most likely explanation is that they refer to two different people. The first is the person who is being pleased and the second is the recipient of the gift.

Comment: I added some context, I guess your suggestion makes sense. thanks.

Comment: +1 but I would say that we can be sure that they refer to two people. Otherwise, I can't see the sentence making sense. Additionally, those two "le" are the indirect object of two different verbs: the first one is the indirect object of "gustar" and the second one the indirect object of "dar".